# Vim YouCompleteMe clang does not complete C++11 'auto' variables

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete

I use the clang completer for the YouCompleteMe vim plugin. I have found that it does not provide predictions for variables declared as type 'auto'.

Is this a known issue? If not, what are the likely configuration parameters I should examine for a solution?

Consider the following code snippet:

```
std::vector <int> persistent_data_container = {1, 2, 3};
const auto &data = persistent_data_container;
data. // on typing this dot, I would expect a list of completion suggestions
```

Comment: As it stands, the question appears not well posed and/or too broad. Can you give an example of a typical situation and what you expect the plugin to do in that case?

Comment: I have updated with a code snippet that illustrates my use case.

Comment: can you share your `.vimrc` and `.ycm_extra_conf.py``

Comment: my .vimrc is quite large and I use a build script to automatically generate .ycm_extra_conf.py from a template. In any case, given that FDinoff confirmed it actually can work and ladislas hinted that the problem could be in my .ycm_extra_conf.py, that was enough for me to find the issue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually isolated the problem using the following approach:

```
:YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics # To retry new config
:YcmDebugInfo # for debug info (derp!)
:messages # for runtime diagnostics
```

This pointed to a syntax error in my .ycm_extra_conf.py template:

```
import os
import ycm_core
flags = ['-std=c++11',
         '-x', 'c++', # <- I had an extra comma here :(
         '-DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER',
         '-I/usr/local/include',
         '-I/usr/include/clang/3.5/include',
         '-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu',
         '-I/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include',
         '-I/usr/include',
         '-I/usr/include/c++/4.9', %s]

# youcompleteme is calling this function to get flags
# You can also set database for flags. Check: JSONCompilationDatabase.html in
# clang-3.2-doc package

def FlagsForFile( filename ):
  return {
    'flags': flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```